# SPTSearch returning SPTListPage but cannot access items

Tags: spotify

So here's my code:

```
SPTSearch.perform(withQuery: "This+Test", queryType: .queryTypePlaylist, accessToken: session.accessToken) { (error:Error?, result:Any?) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        } else {
            print("no errors")
        }

        if let r = result as? SPTListPage {
            print(r)
            if let items = r.items {
                print(items)
            } else {
                print("could not access Items")
            }
        } else {
            print("could not typecast to SPTListPage")
        }
    }
```

and here's the debugging output:

```
no errors
<SPTListPage: 0x600000289290>: 0-18446744073709551615 of 23 items
could not access Items
```

it looks like I'm getting a list page but can't access the items in any way, what's going on?

Comment: I can however access 
                r.totalListLength and it works normally

Answer (score 1):

add "-all_load" to other linker flags